# Why is my Entity Framework Many to Many Table not saving automatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have to classes, VisitModel and VisitorModel, A visitModel can have many VisitorModel and vice versa. After adding both relationship to the modelBuilder, its still not saving to the third auto-generated table. It created the table, but when I try to save, it does not save both Ids. Here is my code:

```
public class VisitorModel
{
    public int VisitorModelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VisitModel> VisitModels { get; set; } 
}
```

and here is the VisitModel class:

```
public class VisitModel
{
    public VisitModel()
    {
        VisitorModels = new List<VisitorModel>();
    }
    public int VisitModelId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public string UserToVisit { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string HostEmail { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int VisitorTypeId { get; set; }
    public int PurposeOfVisitId { get; set; }
    public string OtherPurposeOfVisit { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ArrivalTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckedIn { get; set; }
    public bool IsCheckedOut { get; set; }
    public string BookedBy { get; set; }
    public bool IamHost { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VisitorModel> VisitorModels { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the modelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<VisitModel>()
    .HasMany(up => up.VisitorModels)
    .WithMany(course => course.VisitModels)
    .Map(mc =>
    {
        mc.ToTable("VisitVisitorModel");
        mc.MapLeftKey("VisitModelId");
        mc.MapRightKey("VisitorModelId");
    });
```

When I try to save, it does not save both Ids to the VisitVisitorModel table. The table is always empty. Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the code you are using to save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you followed the [entity framework many-to-many conventions](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx), you don't need a fluent API part to design a junction table.

Entity framework knows, just by looking at your class definitions, that you designed a many-to many relation. Entity Framework will design a proper junction table for you. You should not even mention this junction table in your dbContext:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<VisitModel> VisitModels {get; set;}
    public DbSet<VistitorModel> VistiroModels {get; set}
}
```

**But if I have no DbSet for my junction table, how can I do my joins on VisitModel and VisitorModel?**

The answer is: don't use joins, use the ICollections;

> Give me Names and Address of all VisitorModels that are not deleted togeter with all the arrival times and departure times of their VisitModels that have checked in Today

Normally you would join VisitorModel with the junction table VisitVisitorModel on VisitModelId and join again on VisitModel on VisitorModelId.

But you could also use the ICollectioins:

```
var result = myDbContext.VisitorModels
    .Where(visitorModel => !visitorModel.IsDeleted)
    .Select(visitorModel => new
    {
        // select only the properties of visitorModel you will be using:
        FullName = visitorModel.FullName,
        Address = visitorModel.Address,
        Phone = visitorModel.Phone,
        ... // other properties

        // get ArrivalTime and DepartureTime of all VisitModels that are checked in
        VisitModels = visitorModel.VisitModels
            .Where(visitModel => visitModel.IsCheckedInd)
            .Select(visitModel => new
            {   // again: select only the properties you will be using:
                ArrivalTime = visitModel.ArrivalTime,
                DepartureTime = visitModel.DepartureTime,
                ... // other properties
            })
            .ToList(),
    }
}
```

Because of the proper many-to-many configuration you won't need the junction table, and you won't need to do joins with primary keys and foreign keys. Entity framework will know which joins to do.

Comment: I would really caution against advising someone not to include junction tables as a first-class entity in the `Context`.  It is extremely rare that letting them work automatically has *not* cause a headache for me.  I've almost always ended up having to add them anyway.  At this point, I just include them from the start to avoid potential trouble down the road.

Comment: Wow!, your solution worked like a charm!!!...I can get any list I need even without calling the junction table Thanks. But Please, How do I tie the list to a view?. Thanks once more!.

Comment: I don't agree with the comment of Bradley. Apart from that I've never had any problems living without the junction table, I think that the DbContext should hide whether your data is in a SQL database or an Excel spreadsheet, or a CSV file, or whatever. It's commonly accepted not to require more from your classes than you'll actually need. This enhances re-usability and maintenance

Comment: About how to tie list to a View. I'm not very familiar with System.Web.UI.WebControls.ViewClass, I always use Forms.DataGridView and Forms.BindingSource (so my data can be displayed on several different types of View). If you need a `VisitorModel` with his `Vistitors` use `new VistorModel` and `new Visitor` in your queries. Disadvantage:  You could fill all properties with the disadvantage that  several properties won't be used. This makes your queries slower. Or fill only used properties, Users of your queries get half-initialized classes. Both problems are not detected a compile time.